# List Selection Item

Tags: java, android

I made a scroll list with multiple items. When I click on one item the color of the background of that item changes.

```
public class MyList extends Activity {

PackageManager packMan;
public static ArrayList<ItemList> list;
private ArrayAdapter<ItemList> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.items);
    init();
    create();
    addClickListener();
}

public void init(){
    if(list==null) {
        list = new ArrayList<ItemList>();
        packMan = getPackageManager();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        i.addCategory("com.example.example");
        List<ResolveInfo> items = packMan.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo ri : items) {
            ItemList item = new ItemList();
            item.addName((String) ri.loadLabel(packMan));
            item.addNamePackage(ri.activityInfo.name);
            item.addIcon(ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(packMan));
            list.add(item);
        }
    }
}


private void create(){
    v = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ItemList>(this, R.layout.items, list) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.items, null);
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                icon.setImageDrawable(list.get(position).getIcon());
                TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    };
    v.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void addClickListener(){
    v.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
               av.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DDFFFF"));
        }
    });
}
}
```

I am having a problem. When I select one item others are selected automatically.
How can I resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems that on click on an item you set its background to color DDFFFF, but you never switch them back to their original color once "unselected" . You can either:

- keep track of the only selected item, and switch it back to white before coloring the new one (good if you only have 1 selected item at any time)
- Whiten everyone on click, and then color the new one
- Keep track of the state of each item with a list of booleans (active/inactive), and then override the draw loop to color according to their state

Comment: I want to select multiple items. How can I stop other items from changing color automatically?